# Why does my text not print?

Tags: c, printing, int

Why `printf()` not called in this case? Can we use `&&` in that case or what?

```
{ 
   int zz1,zz2;
   zz1 = 8;
   zz2= zz1 / 2;
   if ( (zz1==! 0 ) && (zz2 ==! 1 ) ){
      printf("!!!!!!!!!!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Check your syntax `(zz1==! 0 )` which programming language did you get that from ?

Comment: @karthikr is `zz1==!0` => `zz1 == !0` **?**

Comment: Your output is more than likely being buffered, since there's no newline

Comment: no, i change zz1==!0 to zz1!=0

Comment: you should start accepting some answers to your questions if you want users to better consider your questions

Comment: @user2570509 **Not** if its a c programming puzzle its a correct code! yes, and if you have typo the it should be `!=`

Comment: @user2570509 what do you means by *`can we use && in that case or what`*

Answer (score 1):

I think you would write `(zz1 != 0 ) && (zz2 != 1 )`.

Actually `(zz1 == !0 ) && (zz2 == !1 )` is a valid syntax but in this case it produces unwanted result because you are writing:

1. `zz1 equals to (not)0 AND zz2 equals to (not)1`
2. That is `zz1 equals to 1 AND zz2 equals to 0`
3. that is false and so the `printf` is not called

Answer (score 1):

`==!` not a single operator but its actually parsed as two operators `==` and `!` because compiler always selects longest token. And `zz1==!0`  is actually `zz1 == !0`.

Note: `!0` is logical-NOT zero that is: **==>** 1.

The code if condition is:

1. `zz1 == !0` **==>** `zz1 == 1`  **==>**  8 == 1 **==>** `False` or  `0`
2. And `0` `&&` `any expression`  **==>** `False`  (according to [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Avoiding_the_execution_of_second_expression.27s_side_effects)).
3. So if condition is false and printf will not called.

If you  add printf in else clause then that will execute. check@[ideone](http://ideone.com/fO5UdI).

Additionally,  suppose if you replace `&&` by `||` even then the printf() function will not called in your code because `zz2 = 4` and `zz2 ==! 1` **==>** `zz2 == !1` **==>** `zz2 == 0` **==>** `4 == 0` **==>** 0.

And `0 || 0 == 0` so if condition will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to write `(zz1 != 0) && (zz2 != 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, your code is correct.

```
zz1 ==! 0 //This is syntactically correct and evaluates to 0, zz1 has the value 4
//4 == 1 evaluates to false ==> 0
```

It evaluates to 0 because you are comparing zz1 to (!0). !0 evaluates to 1. Likewise !1 evaluates to 0. This is not the bitwise NOT operation. It is logical NOT.

```
!9 == !1 == 0.
```

To perform the bitwise NOT operation, use '~' token instead.

```
~1 == -2
~0 == -1
```

The operators for 'not equal to' in C is '!='. To make your code work, change ==! to != 
The operator && performs the logical AND operation.
In the piece of code

```
(zz1 != 0 ) && (zz2 != 1)
```

The first conditional expression is checked. If and only if it is true, will the next conditional expression be checked.
If the first expression(zz1 != 0) is false, the value of the entire expression will be reduced to 0.